# How to support OTA video in custom web app (for LG TV)?

Tags: television, webos, ota, lg, smart-tv

I've searched considerably for this answer (including all WebOS, Enyo, LG specific documentation, and countless Google searches), but have turned up nothing.

In short, the goal is to develop a WebOS application that can resize an existing video stream (coming from coax or HDMI), unfortunately ...

**Update**: This is a web-based app that resides on a server.
After specifying the IP address (via hidden config menu), the TV saves and exits, without any channel scanning, or additional setup.  Upon reboot, it displays the index.html page at the specified IP address.

So, unless there's a way to explicitly configure OTA sources within the web application, I'm assuming that any OTA video will have to be provided via streaming.

[WebOS offers a way to specify media sources from files](http://webostv.developer.lge.com/develop/remaining-backward-compatible/changing-video-source/) -- so, is there any way to point to a video file that's perpetually streaming an OTA source?

Is *Plex*, or *Sling* capable of this?

Any direction that can be offered is greatly appreciated.

Comment: On this site, the green mark denotes that an answer has been accepted. No need to modify the title of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while since I posted this, and I've learned a great deal about this topic since then.  So, for anyone who may run across this, with the same question -- here's the answer ...

When it comes to LG Smart-TVs their are two configuration options specific to commercial TVs (Lodging and Hospital models) ...

"Pro:Centric Wizard" and "EZ-Manager"

The *Pro:Centric Wizard* is intended for hospitals and won't automatically import TV configurations from a server, but it can scan for channels.
The *EZ-Manager* option is intended for lodging/hotels and provides a great deal more control, but the TV configuration and channel listing must all be obtained from a server (or usb drive).

Modification of the TV settings and channel listing is performed by using the FTG File Manager.

- Downloadable Stand-alone Application:
  http://www.lg.com/us/business/display-solutions/ftg
- Online Version:
  http://cct.procentric.tv/ftg_manager

Channels must be either manually programmed within the FTG File Manager, or imported from a TV clone file (created after the TV has performed a channel scan).

In order to create a clone file of scanned channels ...

- Initiate the "Pro:Centric Wizard" setup process
- Scan the channels
- Complete Setup
- Once the TV restarts, hit "Menu"
- Highlight the "General" or "Settings" icon (should be "Settings") and hit "7" seven times (or until clone menu appears).
- The option to export to USB will only appear after pressing "9876" on the remote.

Once the file is exported to USB, it can then be opened within the FTG File Manager and edited for server delivery through the "EZ-Manager" setup.

Hopefully this will help someone. :)

Answer (score 0):

original answer: I'm not sure this is going to be possible.  I believe only system apps are going to have access to the video pipeline.

new answer:

If you can configure your OTA stream to go over HLS, then you can use an `m3u8` playlist for your `<source>` and it should "just work" on a webOS TV.

Comment: Thank you.  You're absolutely right.
In fact, I painfully realized this before returning to this post.  LOL!
I've updated the scope of the question, and would greatly appreciate any suggestions you might be able to offer.